# When having a question URL in clipboard, let me navigate to it when opening the app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I would like to open a Stack Exchange link from clipboard in the app.

For example, if while opening the app it detects a URL to a Stack Overflow question in the clipboard, then it can show a dismissible fadeble banner  that asks whether to show the question in the app (whether to follow the link).

Comment: Not very intuitive, but as the answer to the dupe says, possible.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. My question is about opening a copied link in one touch specifically. It is not a general question on how to open a question knowing its url/id.

Comment: It answers your "How do I open a SE link from clipboard in the app?" by "Paste it into the search box" - two steps. If you insist on having one step I'll reopen, but personally won't support it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard If it were two steps; I wouldn't ask. It is not two steps: you have to navigate to the search box of the specific site (several actions depending on where you are and  the site), then you have to paste your url, then for some reason you have to edit the url so that only the question id  remains; then search and click on the result. I have a specific request: open app and click if I want to follow the copied link. Why even would you object to it?

Comment: That is an interesting idea.  If you copy a URL like: `http://google.com?q=what+is+this+rash` and go to Facebook, they'll ask if you want to share it with the world.  I think we could handle some common cases like question URLs.

Comment: Of course, my wife finds that kind of thing to be a creepy reminder into how terrible and insecure the clipboard really is.

Comment: @BrianNickel: why creepy? It is the primary functionality of the clipboard to exchange data between apps. The app is in the foreground and it doesn't follow the link without the confirmation.

Comment: As a user, you tend to feel the clipboard as something you control.  Copying and pasting are explicit actions.  In reality, the clipboard is something you can add to and any app you visit can choose to read.  If you copy financial data from Safari and paste it into Quicken, you don't expect Candy Crush to then be able to read it and send it to an advertiser.  Scanning the clipboard before an explicit user action isn't necessarily nefarious, it just reminds you of what could be.